# Easy way to find all indices of an array that meet a condition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say, I have an array `[11,12,13,14,15,16]` and I want to get all indices of element that is greater than 13.

I can do it in a hard way:

```
myArray.map((x, idx) => [x, idx]).filter(x => x[0] > 13).map(x => x[1])

>>> [3, 4, 5]
```

Are there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already looks pretty good. It is inconsistency in `x` use that makes the code less readable, that's where destructuring helps.

[`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) is the shortcut for `myArray.map((x, idx) => [idx, x])`:

```
[...myArray.entries()]
.filter(([, x]) => x > 13)
.map(([idx]) => idx)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can be more clear :

```
[11,12,13,14,15,16].reduce((r, c, i) => c > 13 ? r.concat(i) : r, []);
// [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Variables called `r`, `c` and `i` are **not** clear. They are shorter, but hard to understand for someone who doesn't know what they mean in the first place

Comment: r is result, c is current and i is index

Answer (score 1):

You could use map and filter the values.

```js
var data = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    result = data.map((a, i) => a > 13 && i).filter(a => a !== false);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I *really* expected `a > 13 && i` to return `false` here.

Comment: no, if `a > 13`, you get the index. otherwise `false`, which is filtered out in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's *easier*, but you could do it in one function, using reduce (or forEach, if you prefer):

```
[11,12,13,14,15,16].reduce((a,x,i) => {
  if (x > 13) { a.push(i); }
  return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var out = [];
array.forEach((v, idx) => {
  if(v > 13){
    out.push(idx);
  }
})
```